# Convert AttributedString to Markdown

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, markdown, nsattributedstring

I am developing my first ios application and I need to convert `textView.attributedString` to `Markdown`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can find the markdown support here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring

Comment: @Rob I read it, but i couldn’t find anything for my case.

Comment: I don't think there is a all done way to do that. You could enumerate the attributes of the `NSAttributedString`, and add the markdown tags...

Comment: I'm also interested in this and Apple doesn't seem to offer an encoder out of the box.